# What's with "4J" and "J" in database / API names

Tags: neo4j, log4j, twitter4j

I have used Twitter4j, linkedin-j and I'm looking at Neo4j and Bio4j. I've also seen "Log4j" and many other database related names with "j" and "4j" in them. I've been looking and I can't find anything that explains the "j" reference.

What's with the "j" / "4j"? What does it mean, if anything?

Comment: In Neo4j's case it's not really relevant anymore. As you can use it via its server APIs from any language

Comment: In the case of Bio4j, it all started as a Java-based project thus the name (4j -> for Java). Plus, apart from offering a Neo4j implementation we are not affiliated with the nice guys at Neo4j in any way :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know, it is a naming convention meaning "For Java", i.e the library is for Java applications.

Comment: Do you know about Log4j? Similar to the comment on "Bio4j" above? I'm tempted to mark this as correct since it seems to be the consensus response so far...

Comment: seems to be the case! Thanks!